# CodeIgniter session issue?

Tags: codeigniter, session, internet-explorer-9

I have a website developed in CodeIgniter MVC framework.

I have data and that is editable multiple times by the admin and the admin and general users can view the edit history.

My code as follows :

`<a href="<?=base_url('item/history/'.$item_id)?>" target="_blank">History</a>`

( here ***item*** is my controller, ***history*** is my method and ***$item_id*** is the only parameter passed to the history method )

When I click on the ***history*** link it open in a new tab and works fine on chrome, Mozila Firefox, Safari, but when I open it in IE the session is destroyed.

Comment: We will need more information. Could you please post the code of your controller?

Comment: there is lots of code, what piece of code you are looking for...

Comment: at least the 'history' part of your controller?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) by any chance? (and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers))

Comment: No. I tested it over 2 days....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check whether you are creating an object of a controller in any
   view.
2. That controller required authentication / login to get access.